# c# is it faster to concatenate lists and then filter or filter then concatenate

Tags: c#, performance, linq

Let's say, I have 3 lists (no more than 10 in my case).

```
List 1 has m elements
List 2 has n elements
List 3 has p elements
```

It's possible to have duplicates. I need to find the 10 first distinct elements that match a request (I know how to do it that's not the question).

1. Is it faster to concatenate the 3 lists and then filter?
2. Or is it faster to filter the 3 lists (3x10 elements) and then concatenate. And then filter again to have the last 10 elements I wanted.

I would go for the second options but I am not 100% because I don't know the cost of a concatenation and the cost of filtering.

Thanks for any inputs.

**Edit:**
I can have up to 10 lists of 100-1000 elements => between 1000 elements to 10000 elements in the merged list.

In my case, this request can be made 3 to 5 times per second per user (but just once in a while). The lists contains contacts and sometimes, the user searches a contact. I have an ajax request that sends each characters and refreshes a table.

Comment: Do `List1.Distinct(); List2.Distinct(); List3.Distinct();` to get the distinct elements from the 3 lists

Comment: I can have duplicates in the merged list, not in the lists.

Comment: No one batted an eye when this was posted:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array

I see no issue with him posting this question. While this question was obviously structured better and he asked `why` not just `is`. They are essentially both about performance.

Comment: I think that chances are that option 1 is correct. `Filter` operation is more resource consuming than `concatenation`.

Comment: @Adam Are you serious? That question is why is something faster. OP is wondering the reason behind it.

Comment: You obviously need to read the comment to the end.

Comment: @Adam: The problem with this question is that the only correct answer is "depends."  There's not enough information, and there are too many variables that could impact the result.

Comment: @mellamokb I appreciate you taking a more serious approach to responding. I'm defending the right to ask questions about performance of one against the other if asked properly. If the OP would have asked `why`, would it have made a difference?

Comment: Without understanding the problem you can't measure this because you don't know how to do a valid measurement. The outcome is data dependent. I have flagged the passive aggressive "just measure it and don't bother us!" comments for moderator deletion.

Comment: I added some details.

Answer (score 5):

Editted answer: I was previously having a thinko, because for some reason I was thinking of "concatenate" as actually creating a full new list. (Actually, I know part of what the reason is, in that the costs of concatenating strings came to mind, but why that was the case I don't know).

Of course, concatenating in Linq does no such thing, so the choice is between:

```
list1.Concat(list2).Concat(list3) // ...and so on
  .Where(yourFilter)
  .Distinct()
  .Take(10)
```

And:

```
list1.Where(yourFilter)
  .Concat(list2.Where(yourFilter))
  .Concat(list3.Where(yourFilter))
  .Distinct()
  .Take(10)
```

And the difference between them is quite interesting.

From just looking at the code here, we wouldn't expect there to be much difference. We'd expect the latter to have a disadvantage in that it involves slightly more calls, but the former to have the disadvantage of more interface steps being involved in the `Where` implementation that is more complicated than the `Concat` implementation and so these two balance out. The latter comes out as being slightly faster though how much depends on whether the second and/or third `Where` are ever used (they might not be if the `Take` is satisfied before hitting them).

With lists as the sources though, the latter comes out as quite a bit faster, because `Where` is optimised for the case of the source being a `List<T>` and only the latter benefits from that optimisation behind the scenes.

Comment: Interestingly, if the problem set is large enough, OP's option #2 seems to be faster (`.SelectMany(li => li.Where(yourFilter)).Distinct().Take(10)`).  Here is proof if I did it correctly: http://ideone.com/5tGVp9.  Regardless, the OP's problem set is so tiny (30 elements) that there is no real performance difference and the time would be better spent making the code readable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added some details in the questions.

Answer (score 2):

Because I do not have 50 reputations yet I cant use the comment. Sorry dudes.

But, for the question.
In your first case, you will allocate a List as big as your 3 lists.
If you have memory constraint, this might be a bad idea.

So you concat 3 Lists, then filter through this big list. 2 operations.

In the second case, you just have to detect distinct elements in your 3 Lists, access does no cost that much.
I mean, what is the difference between searching in 3 Lists or 1 List?

Comment: Probably stick this in your question under an EDIT notification.

Comment: Which question are you talking about?

Comment: Huh, sorry. Must have been a dyslexic moment: I thought you asked the question, for some reason. Nevermind.

Comment: Might be due to Michael. You were troubled!